# Python regex to match IP-address with /CIDR

Tags: python, regex, ip-address, cidr

```
m = re.findall("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}",s)
```

How do I modify it so it will match not only IPv4, but also something with CIDR like `10.10.10.0/24`?

Answer (score 5):

```
(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?:/\d\d?)?
```

Comment: 400.123.34.56 is matched but not valid (but asdasdasd's regex has the same problem)

Comment: Just FYI, the '/' may need to be escaped in languages such as Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?:/\d{1,2}|)
```

Tested in [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)

Matched:

```
64.33.232.212
64.33.232.212/30
```

Answer (score 1):

I had problems using a regex similar to yours. It was matching 1.2.3.4.5 (as 1.2.3.4) and 1111.2.3.4 (as 111.2.3.4). To avoid matching these, I added look ahead/behind assertions:

```
IP_RE      = re.compile(r"(?<!\d\.)(?<!\d)(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?!\d|(?:\.\d))")
IP_CIDR_RE = re.compile(r"(?<!\d\.)(?<!\d)(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/\d{1,2}(?!\d|(?:\.\d))")
```

The `(?<!\d\.)(?<!\d)` checks that there isn't a number or octet before your first octet (ie: no 1 before 111.2.3.4).
And `(?!\d|(?:\.\d))` checks that there isn't a number/octet after your last (ie: no .5 after 1.2.3.4).

Then, to check that the strings these match are valid IPs (eg: not 277.1.1.1), you can use

`socket.inet_aton(ip) #raises exception if IP is invalid`

Answer (score 1):

There is an `all_matching_cidrs(ip, cidrs)` function in netaddr's ip module; it takes an ip and matches it with a list of CIDR addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Just did a really nice regex that also checks the ip format correctness, isn't to long, and matches subnet length optionally:

```
(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|\d\d|\d).(?1).(?1).(?1)\/?(\d\d)?
```

Comment: Even better: '\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d\b|1\d\d|\d\d|\d)\b\.\b(?1)\b\.\b(?1)\b\.\b(?1)\b\b(\/\d\d|\/\d)?\b'

Answer (score 1):

ReGex ( ip_address with/without CIDR )

try this:

```
str1 = '0.0.0.0/0'
str2 = '255.255.255.255/21'
str3 = '17.2.5.0/21'
str4 = '29.29.206.99'
str5 = '265.265.20.20'

pattern = r"^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)([/][0-3][0-2]?|[/][1-2][0-9]|[/][0-9])?$"


def check_ip(user_input):
    match = re.search(pattern, user_input)
    if match:
        print(f"Yes, IP-address {match.string} is correct")
    else:
        print("No, IP-address is incorrect")


check_ip(str1)
check_ip(str2)
check_ip(str3)
check_ip(str4)
check_ip(str5)
```

output:

```
Yes, IP-address 0.0.0.0/0 is correct

Yes, IP-address 255.255.255.255/21 is correct

Yes, IP-address 17.2.5.0/21 is correct

Yes, IP-address 29.29.206.99 is correct

No, IP-address is incorrect
```

Answer (score 0):

Append `"(?:/\d{1,2})?"`.

That gets you `r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?:/\d{1,2})?"` for a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

this extends your existing expression

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\\\d{1,2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best answer I found is:

```
^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))?$
```