# Python regex to extract network information from logs

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to extract several fields from a log file. I am having trouble with mixtures of IPv4 addresses, subnets and variables. So far I can only match one kind of field (i.e. IP or string).

```py
import re

regex = re.search(
    r'.*(?P<destination_address>\b((?:\d+\.){3}\d+(?:/\d+)?)|\w+)\b(?P<destination_port>\d+)?\b(?P<destination_options>\w)?(?=via|\Z|//)',
    "Myfirewall add 50750 set Mycounter allow udp from any to 123.45.67.89/28  123 via someotheriface"
)

regex2 = re.search(
    r'.*(?P<destination_address>\b((?:\d+\.){3}\d+(?:/\d+)?)|\w+)\b(?P<destination_port>\d+)?\b(?P<destination_options>\w)?(?=via|\Z|//)',
    "Myfirewall add 50750 set Mycounter allow udp from 123.45.67.89/28 to Mynic opt1 opt2,opt3 via someotheriface"
)
```

In both cases, there is no match. I would expect **regex.group("destination_port")=="123"**
and **regex2.group("destination_options")=="opt1 opt2,opt3"** .

What I currently can extract: all required fields up to the keyword "to" (not shown here, LMK if relevant). What I am still struggling with:

- capturing the string between "to" and "via", comment start (//) or newline
- deciding whether it is a constant (IPv4) or variable (string), this is the main part
- separating the main part from secondary parts - ports or options

If a regex for this task is too complicated, I am open to alternative solutions. I have used several other issues to build my regex so far.

[Python regex to match IP-address with /CIDR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229235/python-regex-to-match-ip-address-with-cidr)

[Python regex capture whole integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75568113/python-regex-capture-whole-integer)

[(Python) Regex to extract network-object group from Cisco config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75111595/python-regex-to-extract-network-object-group-from-cisco-config)

Comment: Can you update the question with example strings and the expected matches?

Comment: Your first regex does match, it just doesn't match anything useful. There are many optional fields which the regex engine will skip if it has to in order to capture a match; probably make those obligatory until you get the match you expect and then take it from there. Figuring out what you hoped should match and why requires quite a bit of guesswork. I'm also wondering if you forgot to put whitespace where there should be some. A regex can only match a piece of contiguous text

Comment: Guessing a bit, I would try something like `r'\b(?P<destination_address>(?:\d+\.){3}\d+(?:/\d+)?)\W+(?P<destination_port>\d+)\W+(?P<destination_options>\w+)\W+(?=via|\Z|//)'` for the first expression

Answer (score 0):

*"If a **regex** for this task **is too complicated**, I am **open to alternative solutions**. I have used several other issues to build my regex so far."*

My suggestion to you is to have a look at:

["A human-readable regular expression module for Python"](https://github.com/asweigart/humre). Available on [Github](https://alsweigart.com/) in  the [humre repository](https://github.com/asweigart/humre).

A module developed by [Al Sweigart](https://alsweigart.com/).

As an example the difference between re and Humre:

- American Phone Number **with re**:

```py
import re
re.compile('\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}')
```

- American Phone Number **with Humre**:

```py
from humre import *
compile(exactly(3, DIGIT), "-", exactly(3, DIGIT), "-", exactly(4, DIGIT))
```

Good Luck